# reducer just wont start in hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I am not sure whats happening, but I wrote a simple mapper and reducer script.

And I am testing it against a small dataset (like few lines long).

For some reason reducer is just not starting.. and mapper is executing again and again?

```
12/11/20 09:21:18 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:22:05 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 50%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:22:10 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:32:05 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 50%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:32:11 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:32:20 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 50%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:32:31 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:42:20 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 50%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:42:31 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 0%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:42:32 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 50%  reduce 0%
12/11/20 09:42:50 INFO streaming.StreamJob:  map 100%  reduce 0%
```

Let me know if you want the code also.
Any clues of where I am going wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. My bad..

The error was in my shebang, I just had

```
#!/usr/bin/env
```

instead of

```
 #!/usr/bin/env  python
```

That did the trick :)

Though would be very interested in knowing why did mapper was running again and again if I skipped python from the shebang..

Comment: Hadoop would probably re-run the mapper because Hadoop would see the task as FAILED because your shell would return a non-zero exit code when trying to run your script.